# Repeater controls returning null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, repeater

I currently have a datareader as my datasource which is bound to a repeater. as seen here:

```
Try
            myConnection.Open()
            sqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlText, myConnection)
            dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            cropPlanRepeater.DataSource = dr
            cropPlanRepeater.DataBind()
 Catch ex As Exception

 End Try
```

This launches the databound event, like so:

```
Public Sub CropPlanRepeater_ItemDataBound(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles cropPlanRepeater.ItemDataBound

    Dim rptI As RepeaterItem = e.Item
    Dim AmttoSell = TryCast(rptI.FindControl("amtToSell"), Label)
    AmttoSell.Text = AmttoSell
End Sub
```

For some reason, this findcontrol method, keeps returning "null" or "nothing" I've tried to see if there is a flaw in my heirarchy of controls and whatnot, but I can't find anything.

here's the HTML for a look at how it works:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="cropPlanRepeater" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr align="center" class="top-rpt-head">
                    <th scope="col">
                        Crop
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Production
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Amount to Sell
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Breakeven
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Target Price
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Target Revenue
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Feed Value
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Other Income
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Expenses
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Profit
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                    <!--- this needs to be fixed- incorrect methodology(should be done in the codebehind)----->
                        <%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Crop_Name"))%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <!--- this needs to be fixed- incorrect methodology(should be done in the codebehind)----->
                        <%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Acres_D") * DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Yield_D") + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Acres_I") * DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Yield_I"))%>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                 </tr>
                    <asp:label runat="server" ID="AmtToSell"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Yield_I" Text='<%#Eval("Yield_I") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Yield_D" Text='<%#Eval("Yield_D") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Acres_I" Text='<%#Eval("Acres_I") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Acres_D" Text='<%#Eval("Acres_D") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Storage" Text='<%#Eval("Storage") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Fed" Text='<%#Eval("Fed") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Bartered" Text='<%#Eval("Bartered") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Profit_I" Text='<%#Eval("ProfAcre_I") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:literal runat="server" ID="Profit_D" Text='<%#Eval("ProfAcre_D") %>' Visible="false" />         
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I've tried putting the label inside and outside of the the tables,  and the  to no avail. I'm not sure if there's an issue with my HTML or the codebehind. I need to manipulate that label "amttosell" with a calculation in the codebehind. (I'd do something like amttosell.text = *some calculation from data acquired from the database/posted on the hidden labels above*

Any help would be GREATLY appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CropPlanRepeater_ItemDataBound method handles the header, footer, and the items. For the code you have, you need to wrap it in an `if` block checking that the item type is Item or AlternateItem.

```
Public Sub CropPlanRepeater_ItemDataBound(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles cropPlanRepeater.ItemDataBound

Dim rptI As RepeaterItem = e.Item

if rptI.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OR rptI.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem then
    Dim AmttoSell = TryCast(rptI.FindControl("amtToSell"), Label)
    AmttoSell.Text = AmttoSell

end if
End Sub
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx#Y200